# Combining @Secured and @PreAuthorize annotation on one method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following service method in my application:

```
    @Override
    @Secured({Authority.ACCESS_FUNDING})
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(principal, 'MODIFY')")
    public FundingAllocation newFundingAllocation(FundingAllocationForm fundingAllocationForm) {
      return newFundingAllocation(fundingAllocationForm, null);
    }
```

But I noticed that the `@Secured` annotation is getting ignored, and only `@PreAuthorize` check is performed.

I have the following spring security config:

```
  <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="securityExpressionHandler"/>
  </security:global-method-security>
```

Does anybody knows if its even possible to combine to annotations on one method?

Comment: Can you check this article http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-method-security-using-preauthorize-postauthorize-secured-el/

Answer (score 5):

As per the Javadoc on [`DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/method/DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.html) it will use the first source of metadata it finds. So it is not intended to mix the two. The rationale is also explained in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2116

The [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html) also state:

> You can enable more than one type of annotation in the same
>   application, but only one type should be used for any interface or
>   class as the behaviour will not be well-defined otherwise. If two
>   annotations are found which apply to a particular method, then only
>   one of them will be applied.

So just don't do it and write the correct expression in your `@PreAuthorize`:

```
@PreAuthorized("hasAuthority('ACCESS_FUNDING') and hasPermission(principal, 'MODIFY')")
```

as jmw5598's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42964941/5277820) suggests.

Answer (score 4):

With the `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` you can combine expressions with `and` and `or` operators.

```java
@Override
@PreAuthorized("hasAuthority('ACCESS_FUNDING') and hasPermission(principal, 'MODIFY')")
public FundingAllocation newFundingAllocation(FundingAllocationForm fundingAllocationForm) {
  return newFundingAllocation(fundingAllocationForm, null);
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html